# Using content from answers?

Tags: discussion

If someone takes content from a question or answer with intent for use in a published work, are they required to attribute the original contributor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look back to when you joined there were details then (which of course many of us don't read). Or just look at the bottom of each page; where it says:

> user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

and there's the answer of the licence and requirements for (re)use.

Comment: That actually raises an interesting question.  If an author comes here with questions about their world, and gets an answer, are they required to release the whole book under the same license?  Do they have to thank the poster in the acknowledgements?  I know we can't license this stack under a *more* restrictive license, but is it possible to loosen it under certain conditions?  And would we want to?

Comment: As long as the author fully writes it in their own words and just uses information here to help them accurately portray effects of multiple moons (for example) they are fine and don't legally need to attribute anything. Be polite/nice to thank those that helped but not legally required.

Comment: What Nick said. The CC-BY-SA-3.0 license only applies to what is actually posted on the site. No license (well, a non-disclosure agreement perhaps might, but I think we can safely ignore that aspect here) can impose legal restrictions on what you do with knowledge gained. So copying verbatim requires you to adhere to the terms of CC-BY-SA-3.0, but taking concepts and *writing about them yourself using your own words* does not. The author would be licensing that particular piece of text under CC-BY-SA-3.0, but the license only applies to *others'* use of the posted content, not the owner's.